# Bind physical NICs to containers for docker

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I have 4 NICs installed in my host PC. I want to launch different docker's containers with binding different physical NICs to each container. How can I do for docker?
For VirtualBox, this can be done with creating bridge adapter for each VM of the physical NICs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you expose ports on Docker using the `-P` or `-p` options it is just creating an iptables Destination NAT or DNAT entry. You can even look at those entries by running the command below.

```
iptables -t nat -nL
...    
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0      tcp dpt:8001 to:172.17.0.19:80
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0      tcp dpt:8002 to:172.17.0.20:80
```

By default docker will use the   0.0.0.0/0 (i.e. all interfaces) specification to forward ports too and from docker container hosts. However you could replace those rules to forward only from selected interfaces.

So Say I have two web-servers both wanting to listen on port 80. I would run them as follows. Note that I am not exposing any ports. This so that only our created IP Tables rule allows access to these nodes.

```
docker run --name web1 -t something/web-server
docker run --name web2 -t something/web-server
```

Run docker inspect to get the Virtual IP of the container

```
docker inspect web1 | grep IPAddress
IPAddress": "172.17.0.19",
docker inspect web2 | grep IPAddress
IPAddress": "172.17.0.20",
```

Now add in DNAT rules for the specific interfaces:

```
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d [INTERFACE_1_IP] --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.19:80
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d [INTERFACE_2_IP] --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.20:80
```

Comment: Found this after scouring through current docker docs. Wish I'd gotten this direct answer hours ago.

Answer (score 12):

**Update 2018-05**

After doing some research (which is not very easy if you don't know the right keywords) on this topic I believe there are updated ways to do this depending on whether you are trying to bind Linux or Windows containers to physical NIC ports (solutions not tested):

Linux: Use a `macvlan` network configuration. [See this docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/)

Windows: Use an `External Virtual Switch` for each docker container. [See this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines)

**EDIT**: There is an even easier way to do this on Windows that automatically sets up the External Virtual Switch as noted in [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/advanced#bind-a-network-to-a-specific-network-interface). I have tested this method and it works great. This uses a `transparent` docker network type.

Hopefully this helps future googlers