# Connect Docker container to specific network interface (e.g. eth1)?

Tags: docker, network-programming

I have been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052975/how-could-i-bind-docker-container-to-specific-external-interface), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289351/bind-physical-nics-to-containers-for-docker/50417994#50417994), and all over the Docker documentation. I think I need this explained in much simpler terms.

My Docker container needs to be able to do two things:

1. Connect to a device (a camera) on the host machine
2. Connect to a specific network interface (eth1) to send data

To satisfy them both, I have chosen to run the container as a command given by a superservice. 
My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  superservice:
    image: docker
    command: docker run -it --device=/dev/vchiq my/image-to-run:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      mode: replicated
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

This way I can still `docker stack deploy` my service onto a swarm (otherwise, specifying `--device` doesn't work with swarm mode). When I initiate the swarm I do so with docker `swarm init --advertise-addr my:wlan:ip:addr --data-path-addr eth1`. 
I thought this would route the packets that I'm sending from my container through `eth1` to the destination.

But, when I `tcpdump -i eth1` nothing goes through it. It's all still going through `wlan0`.

Why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: What sort of traffic is running in this container? Outgoing traffic will follow the routing table on your Docker host. If your wlan0 interface has the default route, then that's where the traffic will go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have found to do this is with a simple `sudo route set default eth1`. For some reason I thought that setting `--data-path-addr=eth1` would also set the network interface I used. Apparently, this is not the case.

I haven't spent much time with networking, though that's on my list to learn, so perhaps I'll be able to address the issue with a better solution with some more sophisticated routing. For now, I just `sudo route delete default eth1` when I want to return to the `wlan0` interface.

This is an ok solution for me right now because when the machine is deployed it only uses the eth1 interface.